# TestContainers with spring boot. Where to start the postgrescontainer and where to shut?

Tags: spring-boot

I have following code:

```
public class TestConfig {
    @Container
    protected static PostgreSQLContainer<?> postgresContainer;


    public TestConfig() {
        postgresContainer = new PostgreSQLContainer<>(DockerImageName.parse("citusdata/citus:11.2.1")
                .asCompatibleSubstituteFor("postgres"))//("postgres:11.1")
                .withDatabaseName("test")
                .withUsername("test")
                .withPassword("test");
        postgresContainer.start();
    }
    @Bean
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create()
                .driverClassName(postgresContainer.getDriverClassName())
                .url(postgresContainer.getJdbcUrl())
                .username(postgresContainer.getUsername())
                .password(postgresContainer.getPassword())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean     public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(){
        return new JdbcTemplate(getDataSource());
    }
}


@SpringBootTest(classes = {TestConfig.class,BaseServiceTest.class}, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.MOCK)
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@Testcontainers
public class BaseServiceTest {

}


public class MyRepoImplTest extends BaseServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate template;


    @Test
    void testm1() {
        // will use jdbc template here
    }
}
```

How do I solve the following 2 issues:

1. Say I need access to instance of `postgresContainer` in my Test class, how do I get that?
2. Is starting the container in the constructor of config class the right place? If I don't put it there, the beans that I am creating won't have access to the postgres ports and other info. How can this be addressed?